# Как лучше оформить сие предложение?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как лучше оформить это (выделенное) предложение?

1. Краем глаза заметил, что у тебя на столе шахматы стоят. **Может, сыграем партию, на щелбаны?**

или

2. Краем глаза заметил, что у тебя на столе шахматы стоят. **Может, сыграем партию... на щелбаны?**

или

3. Краем глаза заметил, что у тебя на столе шахматы стоят. **Может, сыграем партию? На щелбаны.**

PS. Перед "на щелбаны" автор делает паузу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все зависит от смысла сказанного.

1. *Краем глаза заметил, что у тебя на столе шахматы стоят. Может, сыграем партию, **на щелбаны**?*

Говорящий имеет **готовое** решение, пауза **небольшая**, уточняющая информация.

2. Краем глаза заметил, что у тебя на столе шахматы стоят. Может, сыграем партию... **на щелбаны?**

Говорящий **задумался**, а потом принял решение. Пауза **увеличенная**, уточнение.

3. *Краем глаза заметил, что у тебя на столе шахматы стоят. Может, сыграем партию? **На щелбаны**.*

Это фактически **первый** вариант, оформленный как отдельное предложение. Пауза **выдержанная** (как в театре, для большего эффекта).

Answer (score 2):

Предлагающий играть:

1. Оговаривает условия.
2. Сомневается.
3. Предлагает сыграть, с заведомо утвержденным условием - щелбаны в случае проигрыша. Более категоричный вариант, чем "1". В отличие от варианта "1", в этом варианте цель не только выиграть, но дать щелбан проигравшему, ну или эти цели равнозначны. В то время как в варианте "1", "на щелбаны" могут быть заменено на любое другое условие без потери значения выигрыша.

Comment: Голос от меня. Очень познавательный ответ и интересная психология, мне нравится.